# Web API return empty string not expected data with status code 200

Tags: c#, webapi

We have a web API which works in one environment, but not in other one.  There is no error, it just returns empty string with 200 status code. Even simply return "Hello World" from web API, it is still the same. what could cause this issue? I am new to web solution and would like to get some help.

This is external webApI controller dll,  for testing purpose, I changed the code as below:

```
using Acs.Tkn;
using Acs.Tkn.Enums;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace GalaxyConnect.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ExternalTokenController : ApiController
    {


        
           [HttpGet]
           public String Get(long clientGuid, long visitGuid, long chartGuid, long userGuid, long workstationGuid, string token, TokenFormat format = TokenFormat.Rtf)
              {
                  try
                  {

                      return "Hello World";
                    // return TokenCommandRepository.GetToken(clientGuid, visitGuid, chartGuid, userGuid, workstationGuid, token);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {

                      var response = new 
 System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                      response.Content = new StringContent(ex.Message);
                      throw new HttpResponseException(response);
                  }

              }

             }
}
```

Still , it doesn't return "Hello World" , instead , it returns "". there is no error message. status ok is 200.

thanks

Comment: Please add your action code

Comment: Do you have a proxy/gateway/whatever infront of your API in the environment that doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Saying something "doesn't work" isn't enough to diagnose the issue. You must post the source code to your API endpoint.

Comment: why are you returning a string in the method signature ? you return an `ActionResult` and in your case its `return Content("Some string","text/plain", Encoding.UTF8)` (If you intend to return a string)

Comment: thanks, I will give it try.

Comment: Also, is there anything that should be done from web API in order to make it work for Https,

Comment: I enable SSL and CORS for web API it is working. thanks